# UWP - Certificate runs out soon. What are my options?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, certificate

Soon my certificate will run out. I read that I would need to create a new certificate. But when doing so all user that have installed the UWP app need to uninstall the app and install the one with the new certificate.

Is that right?

Now I have some questions about this:

1. Can I extend the certification so that all the users don´t have to reinstall the app?
2. If I have to create a new certificate, can I set an expired date more than a year? Currently I would need to create a new certificate every year. Can I change it to 5 years or so?

Comment: Not stupid question at all. I do not understand down votes... especially new coders (or Sunday coders) might find this question useful.

Comment: @Weissu indeed very good question. MS is doing something totally different than Android and Apple as usual and it is normal that devs ask such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I extend the certification so that all the users don´t have to reinstall the app?

Certificate expiration will not effect the installed app. If your users has installed your app before the certificate expiration, they still could be able to use it. But if the new users, they cannot install it, you would have to create a new certificate and create a new package.

> If I have to create a new certificate, can I set an expired date more than a year? Currently I would need to create a new certificate every year. Can I change it to 5 years or so?

No. You could not set expired date more than a year by visual studio. But you could choose to buy a certificate.

Comment: Hi Xavier. Im not that good with certificates. I looked around the internet about buying a certificate. I found a few websites that offer all kinds of certificates. I could not tell which I would need for an UWP app. The UWP app won´t be in a store (it will be sideloaded) if that matters. Do you know what I need to look for?

Comment: @axbeit You need a CA certificate.